# И все-таки «Ваше Императорское Величество» или же «ваше императорское величество»?

Tags: прописная-строчная, обращение, титулы

Друзья, назрел вопрос (очень глупый или лишь банальный – это уже второе дело), прошу помощи. **И все-таки «Ваше Императорское Величество» или же «ваше императорское величество»?**

*Объясню, почему вдруг назрел.*

Довольно часто замечаю в художественной литературе именно первый вариант (Ваше Императорское Величество), причем везде, будь то слова автора между делом, рассуждения героев с уважительным/неуважительным упоминанием монарха или же диалог с непосредственным обращением к монарху.

> Я сама всегда была убеждена в простате этого правила:

официальный документ (не художественная литература) – «Ваше (Императорское) Величество», неофициальный (любые другие тексты) – «ваше (императорское) величество».

Если в художественных диалогах с титулованным лицом я еще пойму (и даже, может быть, сама автоматически ляпну) все с большой буквы, то вот остальное…

> Что вы думаете/в чем точно уверены по этому поводу? Все-таки все
>   просто, как я и думала, пишем везде маленькую, потому как официальных
>   документов не ведем, или все же есть нюансы? С художественными
>   диалогами как быть? Допустимо равноправие большая/маленькая или же
>   есть единственное правило?

**Очень волнует вопрос! Очень жду ответов!**

P.S.: *Прошу не приводить в качестве ответа отсылку к грамоте.ру со следующим текстом-правилом (его я и сама видела, знаю), а вот разъяснение и ваше субъективное мнение буду рада получить*:

«В официальных документах корректно: Его Императорское Величество, Ваша Светлость и т. п.
В остальных случаях корректно: его величество, ваша светлость, их превосходительства.

Обращение необходимо писать с прописных при упоминании полного титула в официальных документах: генеалогическое древо, письмо к монарху, приказ с его подписью (Его Величество король Людовик XIV). Если же к королю обращаются в устной форме (Приказание вашего величества выполнено!) или просто упоминают его в беседе (Мне удалось поговорить с его величеством...), обращение пишется строчными. В переносных выражениях (его величество случай) также используются строчные буквы.

Написание «Его величество» (с прописной только первое слово) корректно в том случае, если местоимение стоит в начале предложения. Все вышесказанное относится ко всем королевским и дворянским титулам.»

Comment: А чем вас этот ответ не устроил-то? По мне, так вполне исчерпывающее объяснение.

Comment: Все просто, замеченная мною практика на письме и дискуссии на форумах, мол, и так и сяк можно, потому что вопрос вдруг спорным оказался. А я сама практик, мне очень важна ЕДИНСТВЕННАЯ истина. Ведь если " и так и сяк" - это уже отсутствие правила! Потому и обращаюсь к неравнодушным и более уверенным, чем я! :)

Comment: Пишут, бывает, и не вполне грамотные люди, а про форумы лучше вообще помолчать. Так что это вовсе не критерий. А ответ, что вы привели, совершенно верный.

Comment: @freim Благодарю за мнение!

Comment: Я не большой эксперт, но вот вам субъективное мнение: вся путаница связана с кальками с европейских языков, особенно с английского. Там заглавная везде. Кроме того, правила имеют свойство меняться, особенно в той части, которая касается не столько языка, сколько этикета.